# PyQt5 internationalization issue with variables

Tags: python, qt, internationalization, translation, pyqt5

I'm trying to translate my application from Finnish to English. I checked the [Riverbank's short doc](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/i18n.html) and got it mostly working. Before I ran the application I call:

```
translator = QTranslator()
translator.load("gui/translations/mainwindow.qm")
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.installTranslator(translator)
```

And the application translates most of the texts correctly if I this on the code: `QCoreApplication.translate("setapikeyheading", "Aseta tunnisteavain")`

Now, my app has few situations where the same error message may arise in different context. I like DRY, so I set up few "constants" like so as a static variables:

```
_UNKNOWN_ERROR = QCoreApplication.translate("unknown_error", "Tuntematon virhe: ")
```

Then I ran pylupdate5 and translated the strings in Linguist. However, during the runtime these messages won't get translated but instead still show Finnish original texts.

Why and how to fix it?  I have a hunch it has something to do with context but I haven't managed to figure it out yet since I haven't been able to find any in-depth documentation of the PyQt's translation (Riverbank's is quite vague).

Also, how I should translate Designer produced UI's with PyQt considering that Riverbank recommends using translate() instead of tr()?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found a hack for context problem. The .ts files the Qt Linguist uses to define the translations and the contexts has line `<location filename="messages.py" line="9"/>` which led me to deduce that the actual location of the strings in sourcefiles are important.

While variables like the one in my question didn't work, functions worked as they seemed to keep the context same according to Linguist/QTranslate:

```
def unknown_error(self):
    return QCoreApplication.translate("unknown_error", "Tuntematon virhe: ")
```

To display the text, I just call `print(messages.unknown_error())`. This feels like a hack to me but it works.